# How to scrape multiple URLs and print them in an individual text file?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to learn bs4 for past few days, I successfully **scraped** a page and print them in a text file so I try to **scrape** multiple pages and the results too print successfully in the terminal but when I try to print them in a text file only the last file get saved and rest of them are not executed. Since I'm new to coding I can't figure out the actual reason.

```
import bs4
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import io

urls = ['https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grove_(nature)','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azadirachta_indica','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olive']

user_agent = UserAgent()

for url in urls:
    page = requests.get(url, headers={"user-agent": user_agent.chrome})
    tree = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    title = tree.find('title').get_text()
    text = tree.find_all('p')[1].get_text()
    name = title + '.txt'

with io.open(name, "w", encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
    text_file.write(text)
    print('files are ready')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
import bs4
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import io

urls = ['https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grove_(nature)','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azadirachta_indica','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olive']

user_agent = UserAgent()

for url in urls:
    page = requests.get(url, headers={"user-agent": user_agent.chrome})
    tree = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    title = tree.find('title').get_text()
    text = tree.find_all('p')[1].get_text()
    name = title + '.txt'

    with io.open(name, "w", encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
        text_file.write(text)
        print('files are ready')
```

Answer (score 0):

You create the file outside the loop. Put the `with` statement in the for-loop like this:

```
import bs4
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import io

urls = ['https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grove_(nature)','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azadirachta_indica','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olive']

user_agent = UserAgent()

for url in urls:
    page = requests.get(url, headers={"user-agent": user_agent.chrome})
    tree = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    title = tree.find('title').get_text()
    text = tree.find_all('p')[1].get_text()
    name = title + '.txt'

    with io.open(name, "w", encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
        text_file.write(text)
        print('files are ready')
```